# Can I connect to a scanner/printer with a VM running tails?

Tags: tails

If I'm running **Tails 2.4** from a **VM** through **Virtual Box** which is running on **Windows 10**, am I able to connect my **Lexmark 2600 Series** printer to the Tails VM session?

The Lexmark  Series scanner/printer is connected to the Window 10 Virtual Box host server with USB and I'm able to scan documents with it to my Windows machine so I know it works properly.

If this is possible, can someone point me to configuring it on the Tails session since I'm not sure if I need to share it out on Windows Host first then connect Tails to it via `\\hostcomputername\sharedprintername`, or configure the VM a certain way via the VM configurations to get it to work from Tails.

I did go to the Simple Scan and Printers options and I'm not sure what to do from there to get it connected, load drivers, and all that type of stuff.

Comment: This is a virtualbox question?

Comment: If this *isn't* about USB passthrough on virtualbox, try reading the [Tails documentation](https://tails.boum.org/doc/sensitive_documents/printing_and_scanning/index.en.html), otherwise read the [VirtualBox documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#idm1631).

Comment: @canonizingironize Thanks for the links, I'll read over it and see if I can figure it out. I was hoping someone here had experience with this setup and could give me detailed on instructions on what they did to make it work but I will read over and see if I can figure it out and if so I will add an answer later with the steps I took.